# Word Vba have problem with printing a large number of files

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

How to tell printer in vba to start printing. Now he only send files to buffer zone. When my program sent ~8 files to print, printer start working, but it print 9 file.

```
Sub Start()
'
' Makro4 Makro
'
'
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    Application.Run MacroName:="PrintMailMergeAsSeparateDocuments"
End Sub
```

```
Sub PrintMailMergeAsSeparateDocuments()

Dim i As Long

With ActiveDocument

    For i = 1 To (.Sections.Count - 1) Step 13

        .PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="s" & i, To:="s" & i + 3 - 1
        .PrintOut Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="s" & i + 3, To:="s" & i + 13 - 1

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

When i have 3 documents (6 files to print for my program) it work fine. But in the office they have about 11 documents to send to the client. Sometimes its 20 so 40 files for the printer may not be a great idea

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't fault my vba code. I go to the word settings, advanced, and turn off **Print in background**.